# Opening xml resources and drawing it

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-resources

I am a total noob just getting into android development and would like to ask for your help.

So I need to get and image/gif from an app which I have the apk file of. I tried using decompilers like ApkTool and more but in the res folder under drawable all files are in xml format then I went into a site called ShapeShifter which is like an xml visualizer but nothing happens when I open the file. So I would like to ask you guys is there a way to open the xml file a view it as an image or gif and will I have to use the decompiled files in android studio. I really need to get the resources of the app like the icons and gifs. Sorry for the noob post but after searching for a long time I didn't find anything.

Code of one of the XML Files:

```
<vector android:height="24.0dip" android:width="24.0dip" android:viewportWidth="24.0" android:viewportHeight="24.0"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#ff1a1919" android:pathData="M7.24,11.057l4.187,-4.788L10.102,5C6.034,9.458 4,11.765 4,11.923c0,0.158 2.035,2.517 6.109,7.077l1.337,-1.257 -4.2,-4.908H19v-1.778" android:fillType="evenOdd" />
</vector>
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Use this link to convert the apk to project http://www.decompileandroid.com.
2.Import the project to android studio.
3.Done!

Comment: Thanks for the tip I am really thankful you took your time to help but I wen I imported the decompiled app (I used APKTool) into Android Studio it still didnt manage to draw the xmls as anything they just stood blank